# How to passing variable value between classes in Java (Android Studio)?

Tags: android, variables, parameter-passing

This is my variable:

```
public class List extends Activity {

double lat;
double lon;

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{
  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){
    lat = loc.getLatitude();
    lon = loc.getLongitude();
  }
.......
}
```

I want to get the lat and lon values here:

```
public class AmbilData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    .....

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String url;

    url = "http://anjayanjay.esy.es?lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon; //here i need the variable value
 .......................
 }
```

I'm new in using android studio, this code has lat = 0, and lon = 0 when I ran it. Could someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: dont know what's your problem and where you call your AsysncTask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass it via constructor:

```
public class List extends Activity {

double lat;
double lon;

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{
  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){
    lat = loc.getLatitude();
    lon = loc.getLongitude();
    new AmbilData(loc).execute();
  }
.......
}

public class AmbilData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private Location mLoc;
    .....

    public AmbilData(Location loc) {
        mLoc = loc;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String url;

    url = "http://anjayanjay.esy.es?lat="+mLoc.getLatitude()+"&lon="+mLoc.getLongitude(); //here i need the variable value
 .......................
 }
```

or through the `Param` of `AsyncTask`, this need change your AsyncTask's first generic type:

```
public class List extends Activity {

double lat;
double lon;

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener{
  @Override
  public void onLocationChanged(Location loc){
    lat = loc.getLatitude();
    lon = loc.getLongitude();
    new AmbilData().execute(loc);
  }
.......
}

public class AmbilData extends AsyncTask<Location, String, String> {
    .....

    protected String doInBackground(Location... arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String url;

    url = "http://anjayanjay.esy.es?lat="+arg0[0].getLatitude()+"&lon="+arg0[0].getLongitude(); //here i need the variable value
 .......................
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see, you get data from an AsynTask. Override `onPostExcute()` in your AsyncTask. Data (String) in `doInbackground()` available here when done. For simple example:

```
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(String string) {
    // Call back Data and Display the current string data in the UI
    activity.callBackDataFromAsyncTask(string);
}
```

Hope this help!